# Django serializer ManyToMany retrun array of names instead of an array of IDs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()..
    code = models.Charfield()...

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()..
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

My serializer

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialier):
   class Meta:
      model= Movie
      fields = ['name',
               'categories',
      ]
```

When i get a Movie by id it returns:

[
{"name": "My Movie",
"categories": [1, 2, 3],
}
]

I want my response to be :
....
"categories": ["Fun", "Adventure", ...]

## What I've tried

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Category
      fields = ['name']
  
   def to_representation(self, instance):
      return instance.name
```

It gives me the expected result, but i dont think it is a clean way to do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can use your models `__str__` method for this. Just use a `StringRelatedField`:

```py
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialier):
   categories = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
   class Meta:
      model= Movie
      fields = ['name', 'categories']
```

and add the `__str__` method to your category model:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    code = models.Charfield()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Option 2**

Use a custom `RelatedField`, like described in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example_1):

```py
class CategoryListingField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.name

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerialier):
   categories = CategoryListingField(many=True)
   class Meta:
      model= Movie
      fields = ['name', 'categories']
```

This is close to what you did, just a little bit cleaner, as a `RelatedField` is designed to accomplish exactly that. Using a custom serializer is not the way to go here, since you dont want to serialize the object itself, but only a specific field from it. Per default, this is the `pk` (or `id`), but by specifying your own related field, you can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: I prefer the second option it is True that is way cleaner than mine, thank you @Hafnernuss

Comment: I would also go with the 2nd option ;) Youre welcome.

Comment: There was missing the queryset parameter when using RelatedField i've added it

Comment: That shouldnt be necessary?

Comment: Yeah either read_only should be set to True, or have a queryset defined one or the other

Answer (score 0):

Add `depth = 1` to your serializer.

This will give you something like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "My Movie",
    "categories": [
      { "id": 1, "name": "Fun", "code": "category_code" }
    ]
  }
]
```

then you can extract whatever you want from this object.